# ini_set not working with nginx & php7-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, php-7, ini-set

I recently moved a project from Apache & PHP5 to nginx & PHP7. When debugging my application I noticed that ini_set is not working anymore, at least for the following settings.

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'On' );

ini_set( 'log_errors', 'On' );
ini_set( 'error_log', __DIR__ROOT . 'var/log/main-errors.log' );
```

Neither `'On'`, `'on'`, `1`, `'1'` nor `true` are working. `ini_get_all()` gives the same results before and after calling `ini_set()`.

I know that I can change these settings in the pool config file, but I just need to enable `display_errors` for one specific part, and the API part of the application uses the same pool, but must log to a separate file.

Is there any way to use `ini_set()` without changing the pool/nginx config files? Or should this work and is this a bug?

---

The following settings however seem to work with `ini_set()`:

```
ini_set( 'memory_limit', '256M' );
ini_set( 'session.save_path', $sessionSettings['save_path'] );
ini_set( 'zlib.output_compression', 'On' );
ini_set( 'zlib.output_compression_level', '3' );
```

Comment: Links in the answer to this similiar question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103807/how-to-can-not-set-php-ini-values-in-run-time-using-ini-set-method Or a simple google search on `ini_set nginx fpm` will give you lots of reading

Comment: I saw that question too, but it's not similar since the settings I'm trying to set are `PHP_INI_ALL` settings, not `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` or `PHP_INI_PERDIR` like in this question. And of course I've already Googled this, but I can't find a solution for this specific settings.

Comment: But the link to setting allowed to be chnaged from a php script may be useful

Comment: And it says "the `display_errors` directive is `PHP_INI_ALL` therefore it may be set anywhere, including with `ini_set()`", so I would say it should work.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar problem with ini_set not working.  apparently the php.ini had ini_set in the disabled_functions directive.  therefore, ini_set would not work until that was changed.

Comment: if it works for some values, then one can refer to:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

for what can be set and can not be set with the ini_set function.  however, if a variable on that list has the Changeable set to: PHP_INI_ALL, and ini_set does not work, then i would suggest to you that ini_set is in the disabled_functions directive for php.ini.

Comment: Like I said in my question, `ini_set` works for some values. It just doen't work for `display_errors`, `log_errors` and `error_log`, which are all `PHP_INI_ALL` directives.

Comment: that is clearly not correct.  from: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php "For example, the output_buffering setting is PHP_INI_PERDIR therefore it may not be set using ini_set(). However, the display_errors directive is PHP_INI_ALL therefore it may be set anywhere, including with ini_set()."  if the value's changeable mode is PHP_INI_ALL, then ini_set CAN set the value.  if that does work, then perhaps ini_set is in the disabled functions.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason.
Any value specified in the php-fpm config as "php_admin_value" or "php_admin_flag" cannot be overridden.

Your phpinfo(); output will show you where these config files are located on your system.